# Modify data in Select-Object

Tags: powershell

I am seeking for help on how to modify the value in Select-Object. I've been trying to find a related posts but I can't find any. Here's my Powershell script below.

```
Write-Host " - Windows Update"

Install-WindowsUpdate -AcceptAll -Install -IgnoreReboot | Out-File "$TempDirectory\WindowsUpdate.log" -Force | Out-Null

$WindowsUpdateContent = Get-Content -Path "$TempDirectory\WindowsUpdate.log"

  ForEach ($WindowsUpdateLogline in $WindowsUpdateContent) {
    if ($WindowsUpdateLogline -like "*Installed*") {
            Write-Host "  - $WindowsUpdateLogline"
        } 
    }
```

Here's the sample data from WindowsUpdate.log.

```
X ComputerName Result      KB        Size Title
- ------------ ------      --        ---- -----
1 TestPC       Accepted    KB123123  65MB 2022-01 Cumulative Update Preview for .Net Framework 3.5
2 TestPC       Downloaded  KB123123  65MB 2022-01 Cumulative Update Preview for .Net Framework 3.5
3 TestPC       Installed   KB123123  65MB 2022-01 Cumulative Update Preview for .Net Framework 3.5
```

Here's the output that I'm getting my script.

```
- Windows Update
 - 3 TestPC       Installed   KB123123  65MB 2022-01 Cimulative Update Preview for .Net Framework 3.5
```

This is the output that I want to accomplish.

```
- Windows Update
 - Installed(KB123123) - 2022-01 Cimulative Update Preview for .Net Framework 3.5
```

Comment: If, instead of using `Out-File` you would use `Export-Csv` this would be so simple

Comment: Why are you writing to a file and then reading it back? Why not assign the output from `Install-WindowsUpdate` directly to a variable?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to PowerShell and this is the solution I can think of.

Comment: I would agree with Mathias here. Would also use `Where-Object` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) meant in his comment, loop over the elements of your object to filter where the `Result` property is equal to **Installed**. As for exporting, I would recommend you to use [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.2) so that, if you need to import it back, you would get an object back instead of having to parse text.

```
$windowsUpdates = Install-WindowsUpdate -AcceptAll -Install -IgnoreReboot
$windowsUpdates | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.Result -eq 'Installed')
    {
        '{0}({1}) - {2}' -f $_.Result, $_.Kb, $_.Title
    }
}
$WindowsUpdates | Export-Csv "$TempDirectory\WindowsUpdate.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I've used Export-CSV and works fine. Thank you so much!